# singly linked list in dev-c++ 4.9.9.2

Tags: c++, list, linked-list, insert

This the C code to a linked list, but this isn't producing the desired output.

```
# include <iostream>
# include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
struct listas
{
    char nombre[30];
    string celular;
    listas *direccionA;
};
listas *listao,*listaaux;
void ingreso();
void mostrar();
int main()
{
    int I,Humanos,Num;
    while(true){
    printf("Numero de personas a registrar: \n");
    scanf("%d", &Humanos); 
    for(I=1; I<=Humanos; I++){
             ingreso();
             }
             mostrar();
    }
}
void ingreso(){
    if(listao==NULL){
        listao=new(listas);
        cout<<"Ingresa el nombre"<<endl;
        cin>>listao->nombre;
        cout<<"Ingresa el numero de celular"<<endl;
        cin>>listao->celular;
        cout<<"Datos ingresados correctamente"<<endl;

        return;
    }
    listaaux=new(listas);
    cout<<"Ingresa el nombre"<<endl;
    cin>>listaaux->nombre;
    cout<<"Ingresa el numero de celular"<<endl;
    cin>>listaaux->celular;
    cout<<"Dato ingresado correctamente"<<endl;
    listao->direccionA=listaaux;
    listaaux->direccionA=NULL;
}
void mostrar(){
    if(listao==NULL){
        cout<<"No hay datos en la Lista"<<endl;
    }
    listaaux=listao;
    cout<<"Los datos de la Lista son: "<<endl;
    while(listao!=NULL){
        cout<<"datos de la persona"<<endl;
        cout<<"Nombre:"<<listao->nombre<<endl;
        cout<<"Celular:"<<listao->celular<<endl;
        listao=listao->direccionA;
    }
    cout<<"----"<<endl;
}
```

and this is the result. It only saves the first and the last date:

[image: Input and Output Snapshot]

But I want save all dates or "n" dates and show all dates but I don't know how to save everything.  I think the problem is in the `ingreso()` function.

Comment: I recommend you read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), learn about [rubber-duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) and how to use an actual debugger to step through your code line by line.

Comment: Sorry friend not able to understand the language as a result not able to understand what kind of help you need

Comment: I need that show all datas added. Not only the first and the last data.

Comment: @HariomSingh Haven't you ever had to read obfuscated code before?

Comment: You cannot expect `listao == NULL` to ever be true when you never set  `listao = NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
listao->direccionA=listaaux;
listaaux->direccionA=NULL;
```

this is only going to link the last node you create and the first node.
you need to assign the new node's next to heads next like this

```
listaaux->direccionA = listao->direccionA;
listao->direccionA = listaaux;
```

Comment: but now stop the program when show the datas "error" and close the execution

Comment: @ Tyger With more than 3 data?

Comment: @HéctorAlonso yes sir. did you try clicking on the link and testing it out?

Comment: you only replaced "listao->direccionA=listaaux;
listaaux->direccionA=NULL;"  for  "listaaux->direccionA = listao->direccionA;
listao->direccionA = listaaux;" ? in the same line? I don't understand how it does not work on mine